# Why does my insert work but not the select?

Tags: c#, sql, select, datatable, insert

So this is pretty weird. I am trying to do a simple select from my C# App to my local database but it doesn't work. I know for a fact the query is correct and that my connection works too since I am able to do inserts. What I want is to be able to put my data from the select into a DataTable. Pretty simple, done it before but doesn't work now...

These are the two queries I mentioned:

```
"SELECT idUsuario 
FROM taxi.dbo.Usuario 
WHERE nombre = '" + usuario + "'"
```

where `usuario` is an actual name that exists in the database. This one doesn't work.

However, this one works:

```
USE [Taxi] 

INSERT INTO [dbo].[Usuario]([nombre], [correo], [tlf],[metodo_pago], [contrasena])
VALUES('" + usuario.nombre + "','" + usuario.correo + "','" + usuario.tlf + "','" + usuario.tarjeta  + "', '" + usuario.contrasena + "')"
```

My complete code:

```
public DataTable ejecutaConsultaDataTable(String consulta)
{
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();

    DataTable dt = new DataTable();

    SqlCommand c = new SqlCommand(consulta, con); //Defino la consulta a realizar.

    try
    {
        this.connection();    // Abro la conexión

        da.SelectCommand = c;

        da.Fill(dt);   // relleno tabla con el resultado de la consulta

        this.closeConnection();

        return dt;
    }
    catch //(Exception ex)   // Tratamiento de errores en la conexión
    {
        this.closeConnection();   // Cierro conexión
        return null;
    }
}

public int ejecutaConsulta(String consulta)
{
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();

    SqlCommand c = new SqlCommand(consulta, con); //Defino la consulta a realizar.

    try
    {
        this.connection();    // Abro la conexión
        da.SelectCommand = c;
        c.ExecuteNonQuery();
        this.closeConnection();

        return 0;
    }
    catch //(Exception ex)   // Tratamiento de errores en la conexión
    {
        this.closeConnection();   // Cierro conexión
        return -1;
    }
}
```

This is the code I use:

```
consulta == query
con == connection
```

Thank you BTW  :)

Comment: NEVER use string concatenation to create SQL commands. This makes your code open to SQL injection attacks. Use parametrized queries instead,

Comment: And can you please be more specific what exactly "doesn't work" means?

Comment: please use ***parameterised queries*** - building SQL queries by concatenation etc. is a recipe for disaster. not only is it a source for many hard to debug syntax errors, it's also a wide, open gate for ***[SQL Injection attacks](https://bobby-tables.com/)***.
 (and no: it _can not_ be repeated often enough)

Comment: You are catching the exceptions but you have removed the code that could tell you what's wrong in the sql passed. Reinsert the _Exception ex_ and then display in some way the content of the _ex.Message_ property. Then we can try to understand the problem. (Show depends on what kind of application you are writing)

Comment: By the way, it seems that _usuario_ is an instance of some class and the _nombre_ property contains the data to search for. Concatenating the name of the variable _usuario_ is not giving you the _nombre_ property. However, look at the other comments and do not use concatenation to build the query.

Comment: It also looks like you have a stray quote in your WHERE clause.  WHERE nombre = '" + usuario + "'"

Comment: First this is a class project and in a previous one I used the same method to build the SQL queries. I still need to learn how to parametrise queries. In future projects I will do it this way. Thank you for the Exception feedback I introduced it.

Comment: Second what i mean by "doesn't work" when executing the query SELECT it connects correctly and builds the query in a correct manner too. The issue is that it doesn't fill the DataTable where I retrieve the data that I expect from the SELECT query execution. On the contrary I can INSERT data without any issue.

Comment: You write _usuario_ in the WHERE condition. But it seems it should be _usuario.nombre_  If usuario is an instance of a class then the concatenation will call ToString on that class and the response of ToString, if it is not overloaded inside the class, will be _namespace.usuario_ not the nombre property

Comment: No change by using usuario.name or the whole route from taxi.dbo.usuario.nombre.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use datatables, here's how to make life easy, and secure:

- Add a new DataSet file to your project
- Double click to open it, right click the surface and choose Add TableAdapter
- Go through the wizard, putting your connection string, then the query

  - Whenever you want some parameter in a SQL string, type it into the wizard by prefixing the parameter name with an @, like this: `SELECT * FROM taxi.dbo.Usuario WHERE nombre = @usuario`
  - When you have a query that has parameters, be sure to give it a good name, like "FillByUsuario" - don't leave it as the default "Fill" or "FillBy"
- Finish the wizard

You'll see a representation of your database table appear, probably called Usuario together with a tableadapter (UsuarioTableAdapter). If you look in the properties for the tableadapter you'll see it has an InsertCommand (and one for update, delete), that is already filled in for you, and parameters.. VS wrote a huge amount of good code for you (it's all in a YourDataSet.Designer.cs file if you want to look at it

To use these new things from your code, just do like:

```
var ta = new UsuarioTableAdapter();
var dt = ta.GetDataByUsuario("hello, put a usuario here");
```

That's all you have to do

If you want to make a change, and save it to the db:

```
dt[0].Nombre = "John";
dt[0].Correo = "1, the street";

ta.Update(dt);
```

You can add as many queries as you like to a tableadapter, but they should be relevant to the table. Right click the UsuarioTableAdapter and choose Add Query. Add another one, maybe `SELECT * FROM Usuario WHERE Correo LIKE @correo` - call it FillByCorreo/GetDataByCorreo. Call it from code like:

```
var dt = ta.GetDataByCorreo("% address here %");
```

Comment: Will try parametrising. Because nothing else seems to work.